# ListViewItem background color

Tags: android, listview

when I show my custom listviewitem to the user, all the items and objects contained in each item have the color that I want,

but when scrooling and selecting ( with onListItemClick ), the items don't change the background color for the desired color

Comment: Can you please post some code so we can see the problem more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to set the cache color hint.  This blog post -- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html -- goes in to how to do that, and why you need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to the `onCreate` method of your activity.

```
your_list_view.setCacheColorHint(0);
```

I had the same issue few days ago and it solved my problem. If you feel it is not what you need to do, then please post some code to have more details.

Comment: sincerely thanks to you all, but after trying all the hints that you have sent, i finally found and solve the problem, that it was under my nose. my view has a custom android:list<view> and on my custom listview definition, i was using the android:background definition for each textview. with this, i was not using the transparent or system defined color for background items on the listview. removed this definition from my custom listview items defenition and the problem was solved. sincerely thanks to you all.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use selector for that. Check this http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/03/customized-listview-items-selection.html

Answer (score 0):

Read this note about CacheColorHints in the android reference guide:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html

it explains the concept behind it and why you need to set it to "#00000000" in your XML or 0 in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, my view has a custom `android:list<view>`, and on my custom listview definition, i was using the `android:background` definition for each textview.

With this, I was not using the transparent or system defined color for background items on the listview.  I removed this definition from my custom listview items definition, and the problem was solved.